# Unable to verify the first certificate using Amazon SDK and Minio

Tags: ssl-certificate, aws-sdk, minio

Trying to connect to a minio server using the following code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var s3  = new AWS.S3({
          accessKeyId: 'minio' ,
          secretAccessKey: 'minio123' ,
          endpoint: 'https://minio.dev' ,
          s3ForcePathStyle: true, // needed with minio?
          signatureVersion: 'v4',
          sslEnabled: false,
          rejectUnauthorized: false
});

// putObject operation.

var params = {Bucket: 'documents', Key: 'testobject', Body: 'Hello from MinIO!!'};

s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err)
       console.log(err)
      else   
       console.log("Successfully uploaded data to documents/testobject");
});

// getObject operation.

var params = {Bucket: 'documents', Key: 'testobject'};

var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('/tmp/mykey');

s3.getObject(params).
on('httpData', function(chunk) { file.write(chunk); }).
on('httpDone', function() { file.end(); }).
send();
```

I get the following error:

```
{ Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1051:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8)
  message: 'unable to verify the first certificate',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: 'minio.dev',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2019-07-11T23:38:45.382Z }
```

I have passed the options "sslEnabled: false", but this doesn't change anything. I've also tried to disable SSL on the node side and it also fails to change the behavior.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to ignore the self signed cert error? (if that is the issue, which I believe it is)

Comment: Do you resolve this problem?

Comment: No, I never figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');

// Allow use with Minio
AWS.NodeHttpClient.sslAgent = new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED !== '0' });

// the rest of the code snippet remains unchanged
```

`rejectUnauthorized: false` is the key. In this example, I've tied it to the existence of a commonly used environment variable that toggles the behavior in the `request` module. AWS SDK doesn't use it for its API, but reusing it seemed appropriate since it performed the same function.

Now if `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` is set, the whole Node process including the AWS SDK will work with mocked HTTPS endpoints.

**WARNING: Only use this in a development environment, such as mocking public services on your local workstation. It can leave you open to Man-In-The-Middle attacks!**